# simple_form nested checkboxes with active record Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

im doing a form using simple_form and i want to do a nested checkbox form, using my model Country, for example:

```
Country has_many states
```

So i want to print the state associations bellow each country

```
[] United States
  [] Alabama
  [] Chicago
  [] Washington
[] Colombia
  [] Cartagena
  [] Bogota
  [] Cali
```

Something like that.

Right now im using this:

```
%label= "#{t('country.countries')}"
    = f.input :countries_id,
              as: :check_boxes,
              label: false,
              collection: (countries).sort_by(&:order_number),
              value_method: :id_class,
              input_html: { checked: true,
                            class: 'js-countries-report-card' }
```

but this only prints the country names, how i can print the associations bellow each country?

Thanks.

edit:

```
%label= "#{t('country.countries')}"
- countries.each do |country|   
    = f.input :countries_id,
              as: :check_boxes,
              label: false,
              collection: country,
              value_method: :id_class,
              input_html: { checked: true,
                            class: 'js-countries-report-card' }      
    - country.states.each do |state|
          = f.input :countries_id,
              as: :check_boxes,
              label: false,
              collection: state,
              value_method: :id_class,
              input_html: { checked: true,
                            class: 'js-countries-report-card' }
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried looping through the country and printing the associations but didnt worked

Comment: Can you show us that code

Comment: done @DickieBoy

Comment: `- country.each do |states|` should be `- country.states.each do |state|`

Comment: oh, yeah, i copied wrong, that was i was doing, the problem is that when i run the code i got this error NoMethodError - undefined method `to_a' for #<Country:0x007fcfd2beaa10>: on the first loop

Comment: Its because `country` isn't a collection its a single country. That information would have been helpful in your question

Comment: How i can print a single country instead of a collection on the simple form? @DickieBoy